# Why can't I template overload?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Why is it that this compiles:

```
class Testable {
public:
    template <bool flag>
    typename std::enable_if<flag>::type
    void foo() { cout << "Yay" << endl; }

    template <bool flag>
    typename std::enable_if<!flag>::type
    void foo() { cout << "Nay" << endl; }
};
```

But not if I define both foos using default types like so:

```
    template <bool flag, typename = typename std::enable_if<flag>::type>
    void foo() { cout << "Yay" << endl; } // (A)

    template <bool flag, typename = typename std::enable_if<!flag>::type>
    void foo() { cout << "Nay" << endl; } // (B)
```

I get this error (first line pointing to the definition of `(B)`, second one pointing to `(A)`):

```
error: 'template<bool flag, class> void Testable::foo()' cannot be overloaded
error: with 'template<bool flag, class>> void Testable::foo()'
```

Comment: @Andy Prowl, you have an error in 1st methods defintion. It's impossible to compile `main.cpp:22:14: error: two or more data types in declaration of ‘foo’`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler complains because the **two function templates have the same signature**. Paragraph 1.3.18 of the C++11 Standard specifies what the signature of a function template is defined by:

> `<function template>` name, parameter type list (8.3.5), enclosing namespace (if any), return type, and
>   template parameter list

As you can see, default template arguments are not part of the signature.

You could work around this problem by changing your definition of `Testable` as follows:

```
class Testable {
public:
    template <bool flag, typename std::enable_if<flag>::type* = nullptr>
    void foo() { cout << "Yay" << endl; } // (A)

    template <bool flag, typename std::enable_if<!flag>::type* = nullptr>
    void foo() { cout << "Nay" << endl; } // (B)
};
```

Comment: That actually still doesn't compile for me (on gcc4.6.3). I get `no matching function for call to 'Testable::foo()'` when I try to just call foo<true>().

Comment: @Barry You have to the `foo` template argument. There is nothing there to deduce it for you. Did you try `obj.foo<true>();` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig - Yeah, my whole main is just `Testable t; t.foo<true>();`

Comment: @Barry mine too, and that both compiles, and works (Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27)).

Comment: @Barry: Maybe try to update to a later version of GCC? I am using 4.7.2 and it compiles that correctly

Comment: @AndyProwl Yeah I copied your code and it doesn't compile on 4.6.3. Guess it was just a compiler bug that they already fixed. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

As noted, two functions cannot have the same signature.

However, I have a different fix.

```
template<std::size_t>
struct secret_enum { enum class type {}; };
template<bool b, std::size_t n=0>
using EnableIf = typename std::enable_if< b, typename secret_enum<n>::type >::type;

class Testable {
public:
  template <bool flag, EnableIf<flag, 0>...>
  void foo() { cout << "Yay" << endl; } // (A)

  template <bool flag, EnableIf<!flag, 1>...>
  void foo() { cout << "Nay" << endl; } // (B)
};
```

where you enumerate your overloads with `0`, `1`, etc, which generates a possible type, which you then `...` to say "0 or more of these", and the types generated are basically impossible to generate `enum` instances.

Sadly, this doesn't work in clang 3.2.  It does in gcc 4.8.